How do I stop the teeth from moving out the gums when moving the jawbone?
I've ran into this problem where the teeth keeps leaving the gums everything, I move the jawbone. I tried searching up how to resolve this, but nothing has worked so far and found little fixes about it. Unsure what to do or how I even managed to fix this problem the last time but I'd like to understand how it happen and what to do to fix and prevent this.
Here's the blender.file
https://workupload.com/file/5YhgUU8Bxq9
My last guess could be a weight paint issue but unsure if that's the case.


For info, just enabling compression when saving your file makes its size go from 29MB to 8MB. This alone would allow more people to download your file quicker, if at all. I invite you to read this guide to share your file, it will greatly help you in making your files easier to share around and give more chances for people to be able to help.

I didn't really know how to share blender files so I sort of just use whatever site I was given to share it but I see I'll try that next time for sure.

Select your armature object. ↹ Tab in pose mode, rotate the jaw to see the inside of the mouth. Then in Properties Editor > Armature object tab > Bone Collections panel, disable all but Face and DEF collections. In Viewport Display panel, disable In Front.
Back in object mode with the armature object selected, ⇧ Shift select the mesh and ↹ Tab into weight paint mode. There, you can ⎇ Alt LMB a deform bone to see its corresponding weights. You can press ⎇ AltZ to toggle bones x-ray.
I personally also like to change the Weight Paint's overlay to be slightly less opaque and show the active zero weight:


Looking around the different weights of the mouth bones, it is very clear that the weights are messed up and need some help. A few examples:
Upper teeth controller influences some lower teeth and upper lip:

Lower lip controller influences parts of the teeth and gums:


Before doing anything, let's go in the menu Weights > Normalize All to make sure no weight groups are over-influencing any vertices (the sum of all influences on a vertex must not go over 1, that's what normalization does).
Then in the tool options, enable Auto Normalize and Multi paint:

Teeth bones special case
For the Teeth bones, since they need to fully control mesh parts that are disconnected from the rest, we don't need to paint gradients of weights, but instead assign one single vertex group at 100% influence on all the teeth mesh parts and nothing else.
In edit mode on the mesh object, select all the mesh. In the modifier properties, delete the Armature modifier targetting the mettarig (you should use the meratig there), and in the other Armature modifier: enable its cage and edit mode visibility toggles so that we can see that modifier's effect in edit mode:

Press A to select all mesh. In the Vertex Properties, find the teeth groups, and for each of them, press the Remove button to make sure they don't influence anything they shouldn't.
Finally, you can press 1 to switch to vertex selection, hover mesh parts that should be bound to the upper teeth controller and press L to select them. If you selected something you didn't want by mistake, you can use ⇧ ShiftL to remove it from the selection. You can also use ⎈ Ctrl⇧ ShiftM to mirror the selection, very useful to select both left and right teeth quickly. Although it might select teeth from the bottom row so be careful.
Once you got all the upper teeth and gums selected, assign them to the upper teeth group. Then you can do the same for the lower side.
Then lock the two teeth vertex groups, go back in edit mode and use the menu Weights > Normalize All, and all your teeth should follow only your teeth bone, but also your face flesh shouldn't be impacted by your teeth bones. You should be able to do this:

Weight painting the face
Now that the teeth are done, the weights are already a lot easier to work on. You can literally move the teeth bones away to better see the inside of the mouth.
Now go through each weight that looks suspicious and make it control what it should. A few tips:

Start from the biggest areas of influence. Like the jaws or cheeks. Because it's their area of influence that will also tell what is left to the smaller ones like lip corners, you don't want to spend time working on lots of small controllers only to then realize you are not correctly deforming to the next big controller.
I find it easier to go in a group to add weight and let the auto-normalization remove the weights from the other groups controlling the vertex than trying to remove weights from a group.

For example:
That neck bone here only influences the back of the neck, because too much influence is left to all the bones that go from the ear along the jaw bone and down to the chin:

Which is why the neck gets crushed down when you open the jaw. The jaw influences the neck.
Instead of removing weights from six different bones, start by adding weights to the one neck bone until you get roughly most of the job done. And only then you can go back and forth with the other weights for small tweaks or removing the tiny leftover weights from other bones that shouldn't influence down there.

Don't hesitate to move your bones far away to crazy places just to highlight some rogue deformations:


THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS! I sat here and messed with each step you said all day which taught me a lot of ways to make everything so much easier and clearer. I may still have to check how much correction I have to do on the weight painting unfortunately but if I can master that I'm one step closer to finishing more projects I have on hold THANK YOU!
